# Roam credentials using CredentialLocker API in UWP apps

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am learning UWP and have a basic app that allows the user to login to a service (Google). I have saved the resulting tokens in PasswordVault provided by the Credentials Locker API.

What I wanted to understand is how I can test if the roaming of credentials is working or not if I am using Visual Studio 2017 i.e. my app is not published Windows Store.

I have a Windows phone and a Windows laptop for testing purposes. I launched the application on my phone and was able to log in and save the tokens in the PasswordVault successfully. However, when I launched the application on my laptop, I was not able to retrieve the credentials which I thought would have roamed over to my PC.

RELEVANT INFO:
[Credential Locker API link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker/)
Both my phone and PC have my personal windows account logged in. They are both trusted devices.

I guess that roaming data will be required to accomplish this task, but I am not sure how to work with password vault in the context of roaming data.

Please let me know if I need to provide any other detail.

Comment: Could you please test with the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PasswordVault) to exclude code issue? If you still have this issue, please provide the os version of  the PC and phone. Is your account a domain account?

Comment: Thank you @SunteenWu-MSFT for your suggestion. I did use the official sample to learn how to use the and am using the same logic. I will try to use the official sample and see if it works as I intend my app to work.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT , so I tested both the official sample and my own app over the weekend and it worked! I had to uninstall my app from my phone and re-launch it on my phone for it to work though. Any ideas as to why I would need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the PasswordVault synced on its own without me having to do anything. The thing is, it didn't work for a week (with me trying all the things I could find to force it to sync) and then suddenly it did. I guess I just have to put my faith in MSFT for things to work from now on :)